# Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: (?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular5

**UserService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
export * from './user.service';
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
readonly rootUrl = 'URL ';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
registerUser() {
  const body: Hero = {
        FirstName: '13',
        LastName: '5451',
        Password: '24',
        Email: 'djfh@gmail.com',
        Phone: '521212121',
        CountryId: '1'}return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + 'SignUp/Register', body);}}
```

This is my model hero.ts

```
export class Hero {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Email: string;
    Password: string;
    Phone: string;
    CountryId: string;
}
```

And this is Heros.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-heroes',
    templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

    hero: Hero = {
        FirstName : 'Racj',
        LastName: 'xlkcj',
        Email: 'rd@gmail.com',
        Password: '103aa56',
        Phone: '90632512',
        CountryId:'1'
    };
constructor(private userService: UserService ) {
    }
 ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.registerUser()
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                if (data.Succeeded == true) {
                    alert('User registration successful');
                }
                else
                    alert(data.Errors[0]);
            });}    
    OnReset()
    {
        this.hero = {


FirstName: '',
            LastName: '',
            Phone: '',
            Password: '',
            Email: '',
            CountryId:''
            }}}
```

user service i want to call onOnit Method so it will initially call the method and save the data to server with help of Web API.
Here i am calling method in ngOnInit() so it's Throwing an Error for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using any feature module?

Comment: no i am not using any feature module

Comment: can you share you app.module code

Comment: import your ``UserService`` in app.module.ts and register it in ``providers []``

Comment: i have already register UserService In app.module

Comment: `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserService } from '../app/heroes/user.service';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroesComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [UserService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})export class AppModule {
}`